# How to use FindSiteMapNodeFromKey(string) Asp.net? Not working

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I need to retrieve some specific URL's in a lot of places of different webfiles. So I start to build a sitemap in XML format. I don't need navigation menu, or breadcrumbs, just simply get the URL by the resourcekey. Unfortunately all readings so far just explain how to set up a navigation menu. And all I've tried so far just has take me to errors.

**I need something like this**, (but throws: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. And also *Mynode1* is always *null*):

```
SiteMapNode MyNode1 = new SiteMapNode(MyXmlSiteMapProvider, "Product1");
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = MyNode1.Url;
```

I also do this:

```
 SiteMapNode MyNode1 = new SiteMapNode(MyXmlSiteMapProvider, "Product1");
    MyNode1= MyXmlSiteMapProvider.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey("Product1");
    HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = MyNode1.Url;
```

I also try with the NameValueCollection and providerAttributes to Initialize MyXmlSiteMapProvider and then BuildSiteMap(), but the same result. (blank link, or error)

**My sitemap looks like this**  (the filename is *web.sitemap*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="~/default.aspx" title="Home"  description="Homepage" resourceKey="home">
    <siteMapNode url="~/products/mainlist.aspx" title="List of products"  description="" resourceKey="listOfProducts" >
        <siteMapNode url="~/products/catA/someproduct.aspx" title="Product tittle"  description="" resourceKey="Product1"/>
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

**My Web.Config file**, have this

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider"
          description="SiteMap provider that reads in .sitemap files."
          type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider"
          siteMapFile="web.sitemap" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that knows a simple way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I am just have same problem like you. Now make sense for me. Check documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider.findsitemapnodefromkey.aspx

> Blockquote
>   The XmlSiteMapProvider class, which is the default site map provider for ASP.NET, uses the URL of a SiteMapNode as a key in the various collections that the classes maintain. Therefore, if a node provides a URL, it must be unique within the scope of the site map provider. If no URL is provided, a unique identifier is generated to identify the SiteMapNode.